# AWS login getting redirected to create account

Tags: amazon-web-services

Tried logging in aws through this.
[image]

But I keep redirecting to this page
https://portal.aws.amazon.com/billing/signup?redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2Faws.amazon.com%2Fregistration-confirmation#/start

The password and credentials is correct.
Because first I entered an old password and I got password incorrect and had to reset the password.

Tried loggin in in-cognito as well. Still no luck.

Not able to sign in.
Where have I gone wrong?
Please do help.

Comment: Talk to AWS support.

Comment: I have contacted AWS through https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Guess 1:** you haven't *completed the whole sign-up procedure*:

- Phone verification
- Payment methods
- Contact details
- Etc.

Follow the prompts and it will take you through the account setup process.

**Guess 2:** you are logging in with *incorrect root account email*. Double check that it's indeed the one you used for signing up before. The registration emails should show the one you signed up with.

**Guess 3:** *browser caching problem*. Try logging in from “incognito” / “privacy” mode in your browser or from a different browser.

(based on the comments below) **Guess 4:** something *else* is broken :) Sign up with a different email address and once you've got a working AWS account go to *Support -> Billing/Account support* and work with AWS Support team to either regain access to the other account or to bring the original email address over to this new one. Billing/Account support is free and doesn't need a support subscription.

However I don't see why signing up under a different email would be a problem. But that's up to you how much trouble you're ready to go through to use the one and only email address you decided to use. It may be far easier to just use a different one.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: But how do i resolve this. I am not able to sign-in to add my details.
And when it gets redirected to signup page and when I try to signup I get an error saying email already taken.

Comment: Can you open a new account with a new address? Or have you got existing resources in this account that you need to manage? May resetting a password perhaps help? Or opening the login page in browser “incognito” / “privacy” mode or in a different browser?

Comment: The password and credentials is correct.
Because first I entered an old password and I got password incorrect and had to reset the password.

Tried loggin in in-cognito as well. Still no luck.

Comment: I want to create an aws account with that particular mail address only.

Comment: @Surya Updated answer with "Guess 4"

Comment: The Guess1 is correct, I haven't completed the sign up properly. I guess I would have to get help from AWS

Comment: Or you could just sign up again. I'm surprised it took you almost two years though! :)

Comment: Yes I could, but I want the account to be with a specific mail-id. If I had to sign-up newly I cannot use that mail-id.

Comment: Anyways, the issue is still not resolved @Tim, so I am left with no choice but sign up again or maybe try GCP.

Comment: You should probably try calling AWS support. They don't provide much support without a support plan, but they might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but for the benefit of anyone who stumbles on this problem,  after clearing cookies, deleting all my history and even trying on a different machine and on my phone..... using in incognito window in Chrome worked perfectly.